Periodic CCSD(T) software?
I'm curious about which quantum chemistry software packages support periodic CCSD(T), and preferably also faster versions such as PNO-CCSD(T) and LNO-CCSD(T).  I've recently been rather frustrated by the inaccuracies of DFT, and really would like to have something better to compare against.  The trouble is that I do need this for periodic systems, and it turns out periodic CCSD(T) is really niche.
At the moment I know of exactly one software package which definitely does fit the bill: PySCF.  It only has CCSD(T), but not the LNO/PNO variants; plus a few (very cool) published papers using it in this way.  I'd like to have something I can cross-check results with, but finding a second package has been pretty hard.  MOLPRO may support this(?), but the documentation is unclear.  Turbomole probably doesn't(?), it has both periodic systems and CCSD(T) but not at the same time.  Gaussian, MRCC, CFOUR don't support this combination as far as I know.
What software packages can to periodic CCSD(T) or PNO/LNO-CCSD(T)?
Please share your experience with this type of calculation, and anything to watch out for (k-point grid?).
I'm also interested in cluster CCSD(T), if there are options (in this case maybe wrappers around other programs) that do that instead.
Review article: Shi et al, "Many-Body Methods for Surface Chemistry Come of Age: Achieving Consensus with Experiments", JACS 2023 https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jacs.3c09616
this compares periodic CCSD(T), cluster CCSD(T) and DMC variants

The CC4S package from Andreas Grüneis's research group can be used to run CCSD(T) calculations with the VASP plane wave program or the FHI-aims numerical atomic orbital (NAO) program.
The program has been used for the calculations in Phys. Rev. X 8, 021043 (2018); for instance.
